# Bootstrap Media class, how to clear:left on the image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please review my code, I'm trying to allow the text message to take up the space beneath the profile photo but it seems the profile photo is taking up the full space and not letting the text flow beneath it! I tried using clearfix but I don't think I am doing it right!!

```css
.rounded{
  border-radius:100%;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Admin Feature</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="news.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="question-news text-center">
<button class="btn btn-default admin-news-question-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newsModal"><b>Admin Announcements</b> <i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="row news-box">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="admin-news">
      <div class="media">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
          <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/184091_469721973060655_360032267_n.jpg?oh=755e7a595507586b075f7c2f4de03eb4&oe=566A8D32&__gda__=1449807500_fd2aec75a083c6907e4827ea6c817139" alt="" class="media-object rounded">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading">
            Administrator <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          </h4>
            <p class="news-font"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum  </p>
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <small><i>Posted on Monday 6pm</i></small>
          &nbsp
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like-btn"></i> 4
          &nbsp
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down dislike-btn"></i> 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row news-box">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="admin-news">
      <div class="media">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
          <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/184091_469721973060655_360032267_n.jpg?oh=755e7a595507586b075f7c2f4de03eb4&oe=566A8D32&__gda__=1449807500_fd2aec75a083c6907e4827ea6c817139" alt="" class="media-object rounded">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading">
            Administrator <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          </h4>
            <p class="news-font"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum  </p>
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <small><i>Posted on Monday 6pm</i></small>
          &nbsp
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like-btn"></i> 4
          &nbsp
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down dislike-btn"></i> 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="newsModal" class="modal fade news-modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog color-modal">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Admin Announcements <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This section is open for users to read the latest annoucements created by the Admin.
        Feel free to "like" or "dislike" the Admin's accouncement.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn admin-news-question-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

running the snippet on here works weirdly, but it is not working if you copy and paste the html file and run it locally with the bootstrap cdn actually working. Any advice is appreciated! please help

Answer (score 1):

Block elements have rigid borders that keeps the elements inside them together inside a box.

Since media-body is a block element, it keeps them together preventing the text inside it to cover below the image.

The anchor tag and the paragraph should be on same level or the media-body should be an inline element. You can try it out by adding following style.

```
.media-body {
    display: inline;
}
```

But you may not wish to override the bootstrap's class styles. It is better if you create a new class for your element and override the display property on that new element.

Comment: you are right it works . working fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11833/

Comment: Glad that it worked. Dont forget to accept an answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using pull-left class, In the bootstrap has also provide media-left.
You check this url, Here is also Explain.
[enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)

And you override the **.media-left a** this css here is , you put the height and width according this your images size, don't forget mention in css **display: inline-block;**